# Which countries do not feature mosquitoes?

Tags: entomology

Please, I am so itchy, I need to know: which countries are free of mosquitoes?

Comment: Iceland is a good choice.

Comment: You'll get itchiness due to dry skin if you move to cold places where there are no mosquitoes.

Comment: Our school geography book told that there exist mosquito in Antarctica (don't know whether t/f but iceland remembered me that). Also in several  quiz-book and competitions I've seen previously that France donot have mosquito  (dont no it is t/f) and there is a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-no-mosquitos-in-France) question also on that.

Answer (score 5):

According to **[India.com](http://www.india.com/travel/articles/this-european-country-does-not-have-a-single-mosquito/)**, **Chris** is right and ***Iceland*** has been declared mosquito free.

The science behind this is quite interesting and there are various hypotheses regarding as to why Iceland doors are shut to mosquitoes. The most preferred hypothesis by scientists, according to **[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/03/world/what-in-the-world/europes-mosquito-free-island-paradise-iceland.html?_r=0)** is >>

> When mosquitoes lay eggs in cold weather, the larvae emerge with a
>   thaw, allowing them to breed and multiply. Iceland, however, typically
>   has three major freezes and thaws a year, creating conditions that may
>   be too unstable for the insect’s survival.